# Databricks and Snowflake

Tags: azure, scala, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks

From Azure Databricks, I'm connecting to Snowflake and loading data into Snowflake table using Scala Databricks Notebook.

When invalid data is passed to a column, I get SnowflakeSQLException. In the exception details, I don't see much information to know which column has an issue.

The Exception message is more generic as below and it is hard to troubleshoot the issue.

Is there any better way to troubleshoot the issue in Databricks Notebook?

Exception Examples:

1. SnowflakeSQLException: Timestamp 'UNK' is not recognized
2. SnowflakeSQLException: Nullable value sent to a non-nullable column

Comment: hello, if those were the exception messages you got then
1. UNK is a text field, looks like you're trying to load text to a timestamp --- you'll need to convert that to a real date value and decide on an arbitrary date value that would never occur in the data, like 1901-01-01, for example
2. It seems that a column has been set with a constraint of NOT NULLand you're sending nulls